# How to truly disable the write cache function(in dmesg) in Ubuntu for an external HDD?

Tags: ubuntu, cache, hdparm

I use `sudo hdparm -W 0 /dev/sdb` to disable the write cache for the HDD,
and the information `/dev/sdb: write-caching =  0 (off)`
shows that the write cache is truly off.

But when I use the instruction `sudo dmesg` it shows that:

```
[23361.915713] sd 32:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
```

I see the write cache is still enabled, I would like to know how to truly disable the write cache function (in dmesg) in Ubuntu for an external HDD.

Answer (score 2):

The `dmesg` output seems to be from when the device was first discovered. It doesn't re-print that every time you alter the settings of the device.

You doing the `hdparm` should truly disable the write cache. You can verify by running `hdparm -W /dev/sdb` to query this again.

Answer (score 1):

USB (MSC/UAS) drives present themselves as SCSI disks to the OS. When the drive behind the scene is a (S)ATA drive, a SCSI-ATA Translation Layer (SATL) is implemented in the firmware of the bridge chip in the adapter / enclosure.

While SATLs do not implement mapping for every command/feature in the ATA/ACS standards, they usually do have mapping for typical features like write cache settings. Either way, the corresponding SCSI feature that is mapped to the write cache setting of the drive, namely the WCE bit of the Caching mode page, is what the kernel would monitor on to determine whether the drive has write cache enabled.

In other words, if after changing the setting with `hdparm` the kernel isn't aware of it, it's because the SATL doesn't detect/reflect the result, or because the kernel didn't get notified.

I myself have an enclosure that does implement the Caching mode page and MODE SENSE / MODE SELECT command, but its WCE bit is not bind to the actual write cache setting at all. Reading / writing the WCE bit does not reflect / change the setting on the drive itself.

In this worst case, if you want to disable write cache and notify the kernel about the new cache setting, you'll need change the actual setting with `hdparm` and the WCE bit on the SATL respectively.

I imagine there would be the case that the WCE bit does reflect the setting, but it requires you to trigger and update on the cached value if the setting was changed with `hdparm`, which makes use of the ATA PASS-THROUGH command to make the change instead. In such a case, it might be sufficient to just avoid using `hdparm` but change the setting via changing the WCE bit. (You can check with `hdparm` or `smartctl` to confirm the actual setting is changed.)

To change the WCE bit, there are at least two ways. One is by using the userspace program `sdparm`:

```
sdparm --set WCE=0 /dev/sdX
```

Another way is by writing `write_through` to the scsi disk `cache_type` sysfs file. You can locate the file with e.g.:

```
find /sys/ -type f -path '*scsi_disk*cache_type'
```

With the help of e.g. `lsscsi` (or `lsusb.py -ui` for USB drives), you should be able to easily identify which one in the `find` results to modify.

(Note that `/sys/block/sdX/queue/write_cache` is NOT the file you are looking for, even when its content *indicates* the current value of the WCE bit as well.)

Also note that both of the settings are likely volatile, meaning that they won't survive a reboot or power cycle, so if you need them to persist, you need to have the aforementioned programs / commands run every boot.

EDIT: I just realized that the enclosure I mentioned actually sets the actual write cache setting to enabled whenever I set WCE, regardless of whether the value requested is `1` or `0`. If you happen to have similar enclosure, make sure you always change the WCE to 0 first, and then you change the actual cache setting with `hdparm`.

Answer (score -1):

To disable write caching on any removable media over USB create a file in
`/etc/udev/rules.d/99-udisks2-usb_mount.rules` (You can call it whatever you want, just make sure it starts with `99` and ends with a `.rules`) and put this inside:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem", ENV{UDISKS_MOUNT_OPTIONS_DEFAULTS}+="sync", ENV{UDISKS_MOUNT_OPTIONS_ALLOW}+="sync"
```

Then reboot or run the command `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`

---

If you want to disable write caching for a specific drive, then you can edit your `/etc/fstab` or by using gnome-disks and modifying the drive options to contain the mount option `sync`

Comment: This disables caching by the VFS, not caching on the drive itself (which is what OP is attempting to do with hdparm)